# Unable to correctly import oracle date data-type column into MYSQL date datatype column

Tags: mysql

After exporting oracle table and trying to import the same into MYSQL,i am facing a problem for the date data-type.The date from oracle when imported into MYSQL is displayed as follows example :'04-05-12' is being imported as '0000-00-00'.I tried the date-time data type, but it gives the same result.Using var char solves the problem but this would not be the ideal solution.Experts could you kindly advise

Comment: You can try to import it into VARCHAR column and then you can do UPDATE with appropriate TO_DATE function.This is not ideal solution, but may help.On other hand, are you importing CSV file? can you post SHOW CREATE TABLE and sample row from CSV?

Comment: Hi rkosegi, i have written a php script to import data into mysql from oracle.Its not a CSV.Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably best to export the data from Oracle formatted in the manner MySQL expects.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(oracle_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM ...
```

However, if that isn't possible, you can use MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function; for example:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (mysql_date) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('04-05-12', '%d-%m-%y'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot eggyal,using STR_TO_DATE solved the problem.Much appreciated.